# Why does the reading of load cell changes with change in the mounting styles?

Tags: classical-mechanics, electronics, weight

[image]

I'm working on a project in which I have connected the loadcell to Arduino via the HX711 ADC. I mounted the load cell in two different configurations as shown in the image. With the connections, hardware components, power supply, room temperature, etc parameters being the same for configuration 1 and configuration 2, I observed:
Config1 has more precise and accurate readings. Drop the weight anywhere onto the weighing platform the readings remain unchanged. While in config2, the readings remain the same provided the load is placed at the exact same place (and orientation) where it was placed during the calibration process. The readings tend to change as the position or the orientation of the weight is changed. I want to know what are underlying principles. Also, can any other style of mounting (other than config 1) yield precise and accurate readings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuration 1 is called a double bending beam configuration, while configuration 2 is a single bending beam configuration. For the sake of simplicity, you can imagine that in the double beam configuration, the weighing platform and the load cell form an angle $\alpha_1$, which is supported by a torsional spring (say, located at the apex of the angle). Also the load cell and ground form another torsional spring supported angle $\alpha_2$.

[image]

Since a torsional spring reacts to torque, you have to determine the torque that is induced by the weight force. Say, the left boundary of the load cell (and with it the first apex) is at $x=0$ and the right boundary of the load cell (and with it the second apex) is at $x=L$. If the weight force $G$ is located at $x=x_0$ then the induced torque on the first (upper) torsional spring is $T_1=G\cdot (L-x_0)$ while the torque acting on the second (lower) torsional spring is $T_2=G\cdot x_0$ (at least approximately, if the initial angles are very small). The corresponding angles are according to Hooke's law
$$\alpha_1=T_1/k\qquad, \qquad \alpha_2=T_2/k$$
where I have assumed that both torsional stiffnesses $k$ are the same due to symmetry. From the angles you get the corresponding translational displacements
$$\Delta y_1 = L\alpha_1 \qquad, \qquad \Delta y_2 = L\alpha_2$$
If you add everything up, you get the total displacement
$$\Delta y = \Delta y_1+\Delta y_2 = \frac{GL}{k}(L-x_0+x_0)=\frac{GL^2}{k}$$
As you can see, the weight position has magically cancelled, which is why load position does not influence the load cell reading for the double bending beam configuration.

Now if you choose the single beam configuration (config 2), then you are suppressing the bending degree of freedom between the load cell and ground: the angle $\alpha_2$ will always be zero (although of course the corresponding torque still exists). Hence, also the displacement $\Delta y_2$ will be zero, and so you deprive the device of the possibility, that both leverage dependencies cancel. The remaining displacement is
$$\Delta y = \Delta y_1 = \frac{GL}{k}(L-x_0)$$
which clearly depends on the load position $x_0$.

Comment: In the single bending beam configuration,  say everything remains the same except I add a few spacers between the load cell and the mounting bracket and place the load cell at an angle to the ground (unlike earlier where it was parallel to the ground). Hence, would it be right to say that the Δy equation will still remain the same because since the load cell is fixed T2 is basically zero?    **The explanation on the double bending beam was truly amazing.  The way the x0 s cancelled out each other to have no influence on Δy amazed me! Thanks Oliver!!

Comment: @GaneshHosur: my pleasure! I am not sure if I understand your desired configuration change. However, anything you change should neither change stiffness of the movement between load cell and ground, nor even change (shorten) the effective bending length. With additional spacers put in series with the mounting bracket, this condition is probably satisfied, if they don't get deformed themselves. The angle is uncritical if it is small enough (say smaller than 1, or 2 degrees). Of course it all depends on your desired weighing precision.